# curl with dockerfile: download not cached always

Tags: curl, dockerfile

I have used curl for multiple downloads in my dockerfile from [here](https://archive.apache.org/dist/nifi/), like this:

```
RUN curl -fSL ${MIRROR_BASE_URL}/${NIFI_BINARY_PATH} -o ${NIFI_BASE_DIR}/nifi-${NIFI_VERSION}-bin.zip \
    && echo "$(curl ${BASE_URL}/${NIFI_BINARY_PATH}.sha256) *${NIFI_BASE_DIR}/nifi-${NIFI_VERSION}-bin.zip" | sha256sum -c - \
...
```

I do it once for 1.22.0, and once for 1.10.0. I observe this in log:

```
=> CACHED [5/9] RUN curl -fSL https://archive.apache.org/dist//nifi/1.22.0/nifi-toolkit-1.22.0-bin.zip -o /opt/nifi/nifi-toolkit-1.22.0-bin.zip  0.0s
=> CACHED [6/9] RUN curl -fSL https://archive.apache.org/dist//nifi/1.22.0/nifi-1.22.0-bin.zip -o /opt/nifi/nifi-1.22.0-bin.zip      0.0s
=> [7/9] RUN curl -fSL https://archive.apache.org/dist//nifi/1.10.0/nifi-1.10.0-bin.zip -o /opt/nifi/nifi-1.10.0-bin.zip 11.6s
```

As can be seen that while first 2 downloads use cached files and thus over immediately, but third download always fetches it from server, causing big time for image build.

Why this difference in behaviour?

Edit:

After some reading and search, I understand that a RUN command actually makes a layer. So if we change any part of RUN command, docker would recreate corresponding layer, and thus downloads happen again. I was continuously making changes in RUN command. I guess that's why download got repeated. Someone may add more to it.